# Failing Sata HDD

Tags: raid, hard-drive, sata

I think my HDD is fried... Could someone confirm or help me restore it?

I was using Hardware RAID 1 Configuration [2 x 160GB SATA HDD] on a CentOS 4 Installation. All of a sudden I started seeing bad sectors on the second HDD which stopped being mirrored. I have removed the RAID array and have tested with SMART which showed the following error:

```
187 Unknown_Attribute       0x003a   001   001   051    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 4645
```

I have no clue what this means, or if I can recover from it. Could someone give me some ideas on how to fix this, or what HDD to get to replace this?

**Complete SMART report:**

```
Smartctl version 5.33 [i686-redhat-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-4 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     GB0160CAABV
Serial Number:    6RX58NAA
Firmware Version: HPG1
User Capacity:    160,041,885,696 bytes
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   7
ATA Standard is:  ATA/ATAPI-7 T13 1532D revision 4a
Local Time is:    Tue Oct 19 13:42:42 2010 COT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
     was completed without error.
     Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
     without error or no self-test has ever 
     been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:    ( 433) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:     (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
     Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
     Suspend Offline collection upon new
     command.
     Offline surface scan supported.
     Self-test supported.
     No Conveyance Self-test supported.
     Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
     power-saving mode.
     Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
     General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:   (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:   (  54) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   253   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0002   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0033   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Always       -       152
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   095   095   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       214
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   078   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       73109713
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       15133
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0033   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Always       -       154
184 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   038   038   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
187 Unknown_Attribute       0x003a   001   001   051    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 4645
189 Unknown_Attribute       0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Unknown_Attribute       0x001a   061   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       656408615
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0000   039   045   000    Old_age   Offline      -       39 (Lifetime Min/Max 0/22)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   070   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       12605265
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0000   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       62

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 4645 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
 CR = Command Register [HEX]
 FR = Features Register [HEX]
 SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
 SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
 CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
 CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
 DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
 DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
 ER = Error register [HEX]
 ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 4645 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15132 hours (630 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 7b 86 b1 ea  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0ab1867b = 179406459

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 02 7b 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:52.796  READ DMA
  ec 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:52.796  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:52.794  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 7b 86 b1 a0 00      00:38:49.991  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 04 79 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:49.935  READ DMA

Error 4644 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15132 hours (630 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 7b 86 b1 ea  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0ab1867b = 179406459

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 79 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:41.517  READ DMA
  ec 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 7b 86 b1 a0 00      00:38:49.991  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 06 77 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:49.935  READ DMA

Error 4643 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15132 hours (630 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 7b 86 b1 ea  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0ab1867b = 179406459

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 06 77 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:41.517  READ DMA
  ec 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 7b 86 b1 a0 00      00:38:41.513  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 06 77 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:38.706  READ DMA

Error 4642 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15132 hours (630 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 7b 86 b1 ea  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0ab1867b = 179406459

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 06 77 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:41.517  READ DMA
  ec 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 7b 86 b1 a0 00      00:38:41.513  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 06 77 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:38.706  READ DMA

Error 4641 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15132 hours (630 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 7b 86 b1 ea  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0ab1867b = 179406459

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 06 77 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:41.517  READ DMA
  ec 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:38:41.515  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 7b 86 b1 a0 00      00:38:41.513  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 06 77 86 b1 ea 00      00:38:38.706  READ DMA

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15131         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15131         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: How did you see bad sectors if it was being hardware RAIDed?

Comment: When the Drive failed, the HardWare Raid became transparent and I could see /dev/sda/ and /dev/sdb/. Funny thing is it showed /dev/sdb as the active HDD. I then decided to check with a Live Linux Distro, and ran the SMART scan along with e2fsck. I then found that my /dev/sda was healthy but my /dev/sdb had errors, proceeded to format and remove RAID setup from BIOS, and then once again run the SMART tool analysis I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

```
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   095   095   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       214
```

and

```
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
```

disk is dead, get data off it ASAP

Comment: Thank you. I dreaded this answer but I had a feeling this was the case. Looking for a replacement right now.

Comment: @Hubert Kario A little more explanation why this disk should be considered dead would be helpful. Which column values to compare for instance...

Comment: @ProBackup: for those two SMART values you want to look at `RAW_VALUE`, if it is non-zero, it means the drive is failing. Any value over 10 means the drive is long dead. `Current_Pending_Sector` sometimes can be "fixed" by performing read and write on the failing sector (`LBA_of_first_error` can be helpful in this regard).